# Linking GoDaddy domaine name to OVH VPS

Tags: vps, godaddy

I'm trying to link my domain name registered at GoDaddy with my VPS from OVH (SoYouStart). I had to created an A Record to point to my IP and it works, however, it sometimes redirects me to the parked page of GoDaddy, which means I still have to change the ServerName. So, to link my domain to my VPS GoDaddy asks me for 2 ServerNames but OVH gave me only one ServerName.

Any clue how to make this thing happen, I searched everywhere none has the right answer.

Thank you!

Comment: What's the domain name? Sometimes redirecting to a GoDaddy parked page sounds like a nameserver issue, not a ServerName one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to have configured multiple `A` records. The domain points at **both** `184.168.221.55` (GoDaddy) and `94.23.211.117` (OVH). Delete the GoDaddy record and you should be fine (note: DNS gets cached, so it may take a few minutes to a few hours for it to stop happening).

Right now, you've accidentally implemented http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS.

Comment: I see, you're right I have the both as you said.
Perfect, I'm gonna delete GoDaddy's record and wait for changes to be applied and accept your answer if everything went fine. Meanwhile you deserve +1

Comment: @WaiylKarim Glad I could help. :-)